# How can I select all entries without a child in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

The table has the following columns

- `CODE VARCHAR(255)` -> the code for the class (NOT UNIQUE) (for example test or test2)
- `FULLPATH VARCHAR(255)` -> the full path including all parent class codes (UNIQUE) (for example test-test2)
- `NAME VARCHAR(255)` -> the printed name (for example 01. Test2)
- `PARENT VARCHAR(255)` -> optional parent code (can be null) (for example test)

What I want to reach now is to `SELECT` the count of all children which don't have any more children (so in a tree the leafs)

I already found a `SELECT` to get all children

```
SELECT a.*, (COUNT(c.CODE)-1) as 'ChildCount'
FROM dir_asset_class AS a 
LEFT JOIN dir_asset_class AS c ON LOCATE(a.CODE, c.FULLPATH) > 0
WHERE a.PARENT IS NULL 
GROUP BY a.CODE
ORDER BY a.NAME ASC
```

This returns all the children without the top parent.

I now tried to get all the Children without children with a subselect which looked something like this:

```
SELECT dac.CODE, dac.FULLPATH
FROM dir_asset_class as dac2 
LEFT JOIN dir_asset_class as dac on locate(dac.CODE, dac2.FULLPATH) > 0 
GROUP BY dac.CODE
HAVING (COUNT(dac.FULLPATH)-1) = 0
```

It works half... it gives me some children without any further children. But a lot are missing.

Is there even a way to solve this without Procedures (So with only subselects?)

Please tell me if further information is required.

EDIT: Link to SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd8ff

Comment: Could you create a sqlfiddle with enough data o be able to test ourselves ?

Comment: Added a link to a sqlfiddle. And I think I found where the problem could maybe be. As the CODE is not Unique and can be used couple of times and I group it by the CODE the multiple rows with the same CODE aren't in the final result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf2f/4)

```
-- get all children that have no child, bottommost children
SELECT c1.*
FROM dir_asset_class as c1
LEFT JOIN dir_asset_class as c2
 ON c1.code != c2.code
   AND (   c2.FULLPATH like CONCAT(c1.code,'-%')
        OR c2.FULLPATH like CONCAT('%-',c1.code,'-%')
        OR c2.FULLPATH like CONCAT('%-',c1.code)
        )
WHERE c2.code IS NULL
```

also here's the sql to get count of all children of root(row with null parent) without having to -1

```
-- get count of all children including grandchild of codes that have no parent
SELECT a.*,COUNT(c.CODE) as 'ChildCount'
FROM dir_asset_class as a 
INNER JOIN dir_asset_class as c -- ON LOCATE(a.CODE, c.FULLPATH) > 0
ON c.FULLPATH like CONCAT(a.CODE,'-%')
WHERE a.PARENT IS NULL
AND a.code != c.code
GROUP BY a.CODE
ORDER BY a.NAME ASC;
```

Update: if FULLPATH is unique and that PARENT references it ..we can use
[this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40f514/1)

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM dir_asset_class as c1
LEFT JOIN dir_asset_class as c2 ON c1.FULLPATH = c2.parent
WHERE c2.code IS NULL
and c1.parent IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This looks already much better than my attempt. But as soon as I add some more "Other" nodes to the Data, it will also fail and even give the parent Nodes with it ([link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/049b62/1)). The Second sql is very helpful, thank you for that, it is even more accurate than mine.

Comment: if you want to exclude parent node just add and c1.parent IS NOT NULL... the logic there right now simply looks at rows without child

Comment: also i notice you added other-other... this is a big problem...because code should be unique..otherwise you have to add id for each row ...or something to tell it's unique.

Comment: I tried it, the problem with the "Other" nodes stays. See this fiddle: [sqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/049b62/2) The FULLPATH is marked as Primary Key and has to be Unique

Comment: try this since you mentioned that FULLPATH is unique... i noticed maybe parent references FULLPATH http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40f514/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work now. And it looks much easier than I first had imagined. Just forgot about the AND clause.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's my take on it :

```
SELECT * FROM `dir_asset_class` WHERE `CODE` NOT IN 
   (SELECT  RIGHT(`PARENT`, LOCATE("-", RPAD(REVERSE(`PARENT`), 255, "-")) - 1) 
   FROM `dir_asset_class` WHERE PARENT IS NOT NULL ) ;
```

The idea is to get all the elements that do not appear in a `parent` value. To do this, we must extract all the last items of the `parent` "tree", which is done with the tricky thing in the subquery. I add a `-` with `RPAD` to be sure to have at least one `-` in the `parent` string, else it would cause problem for the top(s) of the tree(s).

Returns :

```
+--------+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
| CODE   | FULLPATH                      | NAME       | PARENT                 |
+--------+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
| test3  | TEST-test2-test3              | 01. Test3  | TEST-test2             |
| test61 | TEST-test2-test4-test6-test61 | 01. Test61 | TEST-test2-test4-test6 |
| test62 | TEST-test2-test4-test6-test62 | 02. Test62 | TEST-test2-test4-test6 |
| test63 | TEST-test2-test4-test6-test63 | 03. Test63 | TEST-test2-test4-test6 |
| test5  | TEST-test5                    | 02. Test5  | TEST                   |
| other  | TEST-test7-other              | 03. Other  | TEST-test7             |
| test71 | TEST-test7-test71             | 01. Test71 | TEST-test7             |
| test72 | TEST-test7-test72             | 02. Test72 | TEST-test7             |
| other  | Test10-other                  | 01. Other  | Test10                 |
| test9  | test8-test9                   | 01. Test9  | test8                  |
+--------+-------------------------------+------------+------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that seems about right.

Comment: For the example it works quite well, but somehow, when I try executing it on the live data, there are still some Nodes Left out then.

Comment: Can you tell me which ones ?

Comment: Can't Reconstruct it with the sql fiddle :/ But when I try this sql it leaves out some leafs with -other at the end again and also adds some Top Level (who have children) to the list. I'm currently looking into it (also because I now need to get the children with children count of a children)

Comment: Hum okay. Are you sure the `code` column has unique values ? Did you try to set it as a `unique` key ? Is the `parent` column made by a serie of `code` values ?

Comment: No Code is not Unique, but FULLPATH is. The Parent Column is made by the FULLPATH of the Parent

Comment: Okay, then I don't guarantee that my solution works as I considered that when you stated `CODE VARCHAR(255) -> the Unique Code for the class` that it meant that `CODE` was unique.

Comment: Oh, seems like I missed that. Sorry, I edited it in the question. But for now the Solution of Tin Tran is working fine. Thank you for your efforts still.